# Using Logical Equivalences to Prove Tautology

Tags: logic

Using logical equivalencies, show that (P → Q)∨(Q → P) is equivalent to
a tautology.

I am able to prove that this is a tautology using a truth table, but I am a bit stuck on how to do this by using logical equivalencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

use the material equivalence

$$(P \implies Q) \iff \lnot P \vee Q$$
and the associativity and the commutativity of the connector $ \vee$.